# AND operator between multiple values in a function

Tags: python, operators, args, and-operator

I have a function that takes in two list values and returns the AND operator output of them. Now I need to make the function take multiple values and get the output. I have done this for now for two lists of flag values:

```
def and_op(lst1, lst2):
    return np.array([(lst1 & lst2) for lst1,lst2 in zip(lst1, lst2)])

and_op([0,0,1,1,0], [1,0,1,1,1])
```

OUTPUT:

```
array([0,0,1,1,0])
```

I now need to change this function such that the arguments are dynamically given and the number of arguments can be more than two.

```
and_op([0,1,1,0], [1,1,0,1], [1,1,1,0], [0,1,0,1])
```

How can I change the function so I can get output for the case above? I thought of *args, but got super confused on how to use & operator on it.

Comment: Are all arrays have a same length?

Comment: yes. Sorry missed out that detail.

Comment: Well, thanks. I answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `all` function and iterate your args.

```py
def and_op(*args):
    return np.array([int(all([arg[i] for arg in args])) for i in range(len(args[0]))])
```

Comment: Just had a small doubt. If I had to do the same for OR operation, how would that change?

Comment: Then you should use `any` function instead of `all`. It's very easy, isn't it?